# How to use crontab to run a script as nobody

Tags: centos, script, cron, crontab

This is on a CentOS machine. I'm trying to run a script as user nobody (or as a user with minimal permissions) at a certain time every day. Here is nobody:

```
[root@CentOS % ~] grep "^nobody" /etc/passwd  
nobody:x:99:99:Nobody:/:/sbin/nologin
```

here's what I've tried in root's crontab:

setting the Environment variable SUDO_USER=nobody
    15 17  *  *  *  sudo -u nobody /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/bashscript.sh
    15 17  *  *  *  su -c /usr/local/bin/bashscript.sh nobody

I'd like to keep the crontab entry in root's crontab if at all possible. I'd also prefer not fooling with user nobody's account, as I don't want to break anything else that might rely on those settings. I'm not adverse to creating another non-privileged account and giving them a real shell if that's the sticking point.

I'll also admit to being a bit perplexed. I would assume this would be an everyday issue, except my brown belt in google-fu isn't helping much.

Comment: How do you determine whether the script is running under nobody or some other user? Both ways work for me.

Comment: @whitequark - the script creates an output file if it runs. It creates it in /tmp (where I presume user "nobody" has privileges.

Comment: also, there's no   /etc/cron.d/crontab.allow, or  /etc/cron.d/crontab.deny on the system.

Comment: Did you tried running it with `su nobody` manually? Did you checked cron logs (syslog output maybe) after it was supposed to be run?

Comment: @whitequark - cron has logs? let me look

Jan 21 18:25:01 `uname -n` crond[7776]: (root) CMD (su -c /usr/local/bin/bashscript.sh nobody)

so root is in those parentheses, so that's who ran the script. but running that on the command line gets me "This account is currently not available." b/c /etc/passwd is set to nologin

Comment: @whitequark sudo -u nobody /usr/local/bin/bashscript.sh    does work from the root prompt, let me run it again from crontab and look at the logs...

Comment: @whitequark (crontab line first, log line 2nd [redacted])

18 19 *  *  *   sudo -u nobody /usr/local/bin/script.sh

Jan 21 19:18:01 fakename crond[14653]: (root) CMD (sudo -u nobody /usr/local/bin/script.sh)

above did not create the output file but works from command line OK

Comment: 25 19 * * * sudo -u pica /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/bashscript.sh   (running as my account, an active account that can sudo, did not work in crontab, but again did work from the root command line)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you are posting the contents of `crontab -e` or `crontab -l`?

This is the crontab file beloning to user "root", and that file does not support specifying a user to run the command as (as it's generally a file used for scheduling *personal* jobs).
Look at `/etc/crontab` instead which is the system-wide crontab and has an additional field: the **user** field. Try adding a line like this to `/etc/crontab`:

```
15 17 * * * nobody /usr/local/bin/bashscript.sh
```

Comment: Existing practice everywhere I've seen is to do the day to day maintenance jobs in root's crontab. I suppose that's a bad practice because there is a field to put in the user that the cronjob should be run under.  I've never even heard of /etc/crontab before.  

This makes for a better answer than my workaround.

Comment: actually /etc/cron.d/ seems to be the preferred location over /etc/crontab . Ubuntu documentation says /etc/crontab could be affected by updates.

Answer (score 2):

su --shell=/bin/bash --session-command="/path/to/command -argument=something" username &

Works for me and doesn't throw the "This account is currently not available." error even when the user doesn't have a valid login shell

Answer (score 1):

Actually ***clawspoon*** lead me to the answer, but let me create my own, more complete answer so it can float to the top.

I don't know how common it is, but some online Ubuntu documentation says that /etc/crontab can be overwritten upon upgrade, and the preferred solution is to create a file called /etc/cron.d/anything (where anything can be, well, anything. Any filename)

I've created a file called /etc/cron.d/nobody and I'm putting the scripts to run as a non-privileged user. example lines:

```
# run the following every day at 01:02 AM
02 01 *  *  *  nobody /usr/local/bin/script-to-run-as-nobody.sh
```

I've put a comment in root's crontab for others to follow, as day to day crontab jobs are currently all being run from there. Not exactly the best practice.

Also, for testing purposes, I need to first run the job via the command line. since I have sudo privlages, I use:

```
$ sudo -u root sudo -u nobody /usr/local/bin/script-to-run-as-nobody.sh
```

If that script needs to output to **/dev/stderr** or **/dev/stdout**, then do the following:

```
$ chmod o+w /dev/ttyp1
```

and do a:

```
$ chmod o-w /dev/ttyp1
```

when you are finished testing to prevent just anyone from sending junk to your terminal screen. (the actual terminal you are using may differ from **/dev/tty1**, so do a **$ ls -ltr /dev/tty*|grep username** to find out which one is yours).

Answer (score 0):

Workaround instead of a real answer:

You can add a comment to your crontab

```
**#see crontab -u nobody -l for something that runs everyday at 1:15 AM**
```

and then just add an entry to the user "nobody" crontab. I used:

```
**15 1 *  *  *   /usr/local/bin/script.sh #comment**
```

Answer (score 0):

workaround #2

you can create an unprivileged user that does have a login shell in /etc/passwd

say, create a user called "somebody", deny them sudo, but give them a shell

Then the following should work in root's crontab:

```
15 1  *  *  *  su -c /usr/local/bin/bashscript.sh somebody
```

I like the /etc/crontab answer by clawspoon better though.